# React non state variables inside function component are not updated instantly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, console

I know that useState hook of react is asynchronous so if I use useState to store variable and call set function on it, it may not be updated instantly.

However now I am using simple variables to store the value, but still the variable value is not updated. How can I resolve the same?

```
const List=(props)=>{
    let count = 1;
    const onNextButtonClick = ()=>{
        count  = count +1;
        console.log(count );
        updatePage();
    }
    return (
        //html
    )
}
```

I see that the value of c is not getting incremented whenever the next button is clicked and I am getting the same value of c on console.

Why is this happening?

Comment: `count` should be stored in state.

Comment: Every time you render the component it's reset to 1.

Comment: As @Andy said, if you don't use the hook useState to store the count, your html won't be rendered whenever there is a change in the value of c

Comment: but @Andy in my case html does gets re-rendered even without using hooks

Comment: I am not sure, can you post the fiddle link?

Comment: But, as @jonrsharpe said, everytime the component is re-rendered the count is set to 1. Every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`count` needs to be stored in state and, because state updates may be grouped and processed asynchronously, you won't see the change until the next render which is where [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) comes in useful.

```js
const { useEffect, useState } = React;

function Example() {

  const [ count, setCount ] = useState(0);

  function onNextButtonClick() {
    setCount(count + 1);
    // the other thing
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (count) console.log(count);
  }, [count]);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={onNextButtonClick}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but any idea why my component was getting rerendered even without using state hook

Comment: @GBDGBDA depends on what `updatePage` does.

Comment: Also since there can be one use effect in my code, what if I have multiple logic in place, how do I segregate them inside useeffect hook

Comment: You can have as many `useEffect`s as you need. I only included it in my example to show you the result of the state being updated.

Comment: okay one last question, lets say I have this variable count, whenevr count changes useEffect will also run, but even if I don't update my count, it will still run whenever my component is mounted or updated

Comment: You can put in a check. I've updated my answer with a change to the `useEffect`. It won't change if `count` hasn't changed.