# How can I dynamically choose an array element and output it to a page in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-tsx

I have custom hook useTimetables() that returns an array of timetables. After receiving it I want to choose some day depending on what day is it today. Then I want to output this day, previous and next, but somehow my code outputs only current day. Moreover, while debugging "currentDay" remains undefined or not available, but in the end only it is displayed on the screen.
Can somebody give me an advise? I will be grateful.

Here is the code:

```
export function MainPage() {
    const [previousDay, setPreviousDay] = useState<ITimetable>()
    const [currentDay, setCurrentDay] = useState<ITimetable>()
    const [nextDay, setNextDay] = useState<ITimetable>()

    const [previousIndex, setPreviousIndex] = useState<number>()
    const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState<number>()
    const [nextIndex, setNextIndex] = useState<number>()

    const { timetables, loading, error } = useTimetables()
    
    useEffect(() => {
        initCurrentDay()
    }, [timetables])

    function initCurrentDay() {
        if (timetables.length > 0) {
            if (moment() < moment(timetables[0].date, "dddd - DD/MM/YY")) {
                setCurrentDay(timetables[0])
                setCurrentIndex(0)
            }
            else if (moment() > moment(timetables[timetables.length - 1].date, "dddd - DD/MM/YY")) {
                setCurrentDay(timetables[timetables.length - 1])
                setCurrentIndex(timetables.length - 1)
            }
            else {
                for (let i = 0; i < timetables.length; i++) {
                    if (moment(timetables[i].date, "dddd - DD/MM/YY") === moment()) {
                        setCurrentDay(timetables[i])
                        setCurrentIndex(i)
                    }
                }
            }
            initPreviousAndNext()
        }
    }

    function initPreviousAndNext() {
        if (currentIndex === undefined) return
        if (currentIndex !== 0) {
            setPreviousIndex(currentIndex - 1)
            setPreviousDay(timetables[previousIndex!!])
        } 
        if (currentIndex !== timetables.length - 1) {
            setNextIndex(currentIndex + 1)
            setNextDay(timetables[nextIndex!!])
        }
    }
    
    return (
    <>
        <NavigationPanel></NavigationPanel>
        { loading && <div>Loading...</div>}
        { error && <div>{ error }</div>}
        { timetables.length > 0 &&
            <div className="timetables-view">
                <div className="previous-timetable">
                    {previousDay && <Timetable timetable={ previousDay!! } key={ previousDay!!.id }></Timetable> }
                </div>
                {currentDay &&
                    <div className="current-timetable">
                        {previousDay && <img src = { arrowLeft } alt="arrow to change the day to the previous"></img>}
                        <CurrentTimetable timetable={ currentDay!! } key={ currentDay!!.id }></CurrentTimetable>
                        {nextDay && <img src = { arrowRight } alt="arrow to change the day to the next"></img>}
                    </div>
                }
                <div className="next-timetable">
                    { nextDay && <Timetable timetable={ nextDay!! } key={ nextDay!!.id }></Timetable> }
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </>
    );
}
```

Comment: In `initPreviousAndNext()`, the value of `previousIndex` is not updated instantly when you call `setPreviousIndex`. Instead of `timetables[previousIndex!!]` you can just use `timetables[currentIndex - 1]` (and similarly for `nextIndex`). [See previous discussion of what's going on here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69602256/21146235).

Comment: didn't work for me, only current day is displayed